# TypeScript: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

For some reason I can not run my React app, because following error:

*TypeScript: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.*

I am exporting my TS type based on my API data:

```
export type CartItemType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  amount: number;
  chair: {
    name: string;
    colors: {
      white: {
        hex: string;
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Fetching the data:

```
  const getProducts = async (): Promise<CartItemType[]> =>
  await (await fetch("apiEndpoint")).json();

 const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([] as CartItemType[]);
 const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery<CartItemType[]>(
    "products",
    getProducts
  );
```

I would like to select the fetched data and I am doing it in such a way:

```
const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = React.useState([]);

{data?.map((item) => (
            <button onClick={() => setSelectedData(item)}>SHOW</button>
{selectedData === item ? (
                <p>{selectedData.chair.description}</p>
 ) : null}
```

Unfortunately I am having this error on selectedData:

**This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'any[]' and 'CartItemType' have no overlap.**

I don't really know what that means and how to fix it.
[image]

It would work only when I would specify the number in object array like this:

```
selectedData[0].name
```

But I have to make it work for `selectedData.name`

Comment: pls share minimum reproducable example

Comment: Why do you pass an empty array to `useState`? What should your code do on first render, when `selectedData` is equal to this empty array?

Comment: It should be just empty by default and when clicking on any data, state should be updated and data should be shown. @Cerberus

Comment: You're initializing `selectedData` as an empty array `any[]` and comparing it to a single object of type `CartItemType`. There's is no condition under which that comparision would return `true`: how could they ever be the same object?

Comment: I created an example @Ibsn here: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-data-forked-8so38?file=/src/App.tsx, this is my first TS project ever.

Comment: There are several issues on the example you provided. As for the one mentioned in your question: if `selectedData` is going to hold a single object of type `CartItemType` you should initialize it as a single object of type `CartItemType` (or as `undefined`), not as an empty array. So try this: `const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = React.useState<CartItemType>({} as CartItemType);`

Comment: `selectedItem === item` is always going to return false. You can't really compare objects like this in JavaScript/Typescript. `===` will only work if you compare primitive values,  e.i : String, Number, Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You must aware of the value that the state is going to hold. It is important because the state update cause the re-render of the application.

Change your initial value of `selectedData` state variable to `{}`.

```
const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = React.useState({} as CartItemType);
```

Reason: Initially you are holding array value in a state and then later you are setting the state with objects and performed operation assuming it's an object. So, it's obvious that you must hold object value in the `selectedData`  state.

This is the reason that you are getting this error message.

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'any[]' and 'CartItemType' have no overlap.
```

The good part: I have made that change in the sandbox and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will fix the error but ideally you want to avoid [Type casting](https://dev.to/ylerjen/typescript-cast-is-a-type-breaker-1jbh)

In my opinion, it is safer to set `selectedData` to `null` first to make sure you only use it if it has a correct value:

```
const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = React.useState<CartItemType | null>(null);
```

Then in your code you can do

```
if(selectedData) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
selectedData ? ... :
```